# Maintain sidenav expand state after route changes

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Is there a way to keep the state of expanded sidenav node without using any state management?
As of currently the expanded sidenav node will reset every time route changed.
Almost seems like navbar component is being destroyed over and over again.

[image]

**navbar.component.html**

```
<mat-sidenav-container [hasBackdrop]="true" autosize>
  <mat-sidenav fixedTopGap="60" fixedInViewport="true" #sidenav mode="over">
    <mat-list-item>Modules</mat-list-item>

    <mat-tree
      [dataSource]="dataSource"
      [treeControl]="treeControl"
      class="tree"
    >
      <ng-container *matTreeNodeDef="let node">
        <mat-tree-node routerLinkActive="active" matTreeNodeToggle>
          <a class="full-content" [routerLink]="[node.link]" mat-icon-button>
            <div style="text-align: left;">
              <mat-icon mat-icon-button>{{ node.icon }}</mat-icon>
              <mat-label>{{ node.name }}</mat-label>
            </div>
          </a>
        </mat-tree-node>
      </ng-container>

      <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
        <li>
          <div class="mat-tree-node">
            <button
              matTreeNodeToggle
              class="full-content-button"
              mat-icon-button
              [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name"
              (click)="changeState(node)"
            >
              <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rt1-mirror">
                {{
                  treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_less' : 'expand_more'
                }}
              </mat-icon>
              {{ node.name }}
            </button>
          </div>

          <ul [class.tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
            <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
          </ul>
          <hr />
        </li>
      </mat-nested-tree-node>
    </mat-tree>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**navbar.component.ts**

```
import * as CryptoJS from "crypto-js";
import cloneDeep from 'lodash.clonedeep';
import { ActivatedRoute, Data, Router, UrlSegment } from '@angular/router';
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  OnDestroy,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, combineLatest, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { excludedModule } from 'src/app/shared/type-casting/enum/navbar-exclude.enum';
import { INavBarMenu } from '../../../models/modules/general/navbar/NavBar.model';
import { LocalStorageService } from './../../../util/localStorage/local-storage.service';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material';
import { NavBarService } from './../../../../core/services/general/navbar/navbar.service';
import { NestedTreeControl } from '@angular/cdk/tree';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('sidenav') _sidenav: MatSidenav;

  /** @value Cater opacity value of '0' & '1' */
  private isFooterShownSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(+false);
  readonly isFooterShown$ = this.isFooterShownSubject.asObservable();

  public dataSource: INavBarMenu[];
  public treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<INavBarMenu>(
    node => node.children
  );
  private enumExcludedModule = Object.values(excludedModule);
  private subscriptions = new Subscription();
  private route: Data;

  constructor(
    private _navBarService: NavBarService,
    private _acRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router,
    private _localStorage: LocalStorageService
  ) {
    this.route = _acRoute.snapshot.root.firstChild.children[0].children[0];

    /** @execute multiple subscription in parallel, then take only latest subscription */
    combineLatest(this.getMenuDetails(), _acRoute.url).subscribe(
      ([res]: [INavBarMenu[], UrlSegment[]]) => {
        const clonedRes: INavBarMenu[] = cloneDeep(res);

        const accessRights = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
           JSON.stringify(clonedRes),
           "Secret Passphrase"
          ); 
        localStorage.setItem('accessRights', accessRights);

        /** @mutation - changed object reference of clonedRes, lastly this.dataSource assigned value of mutated clonedRes */
        clonedRes.forEach(el =>
          this.enumExcludedModule.forEach(
            exclude =>
              (el.children = Object.values(el.children).filter(
                value => value.link !== exclude
              ))
          )
        );
        this.dataSource = clonedRes;
      }
    );
  }

  onScroll(event: any) {
    /** @logic visible height + pixel scrolled >= total height */
    event.target.offsetHeight + event.target.scrollTop >=
    event.target.scrollHeight
      ? this.isFooterShownSubject.next(+1)
      : this.isFooterShownSubject.next(+0);
  }

  hasChild = (_: number, node: INavBarMenu) =>
    !!node.children && node.children.length > 0;

  ngOnInit() {}

  goHome() {
    this._router.navigate(['/homepage']);
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.clear();
    this._router.navigate(['/login']);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  }

  changeState(node) {
    console.log(node);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**NavBar.model.ts**

```
export class INavBarMenu {
  constructor(

    public id: number,
    public name: string,

    public pView: string,
    public pAdd: string,
    public pEdit: string,
    public pDelete: string,

    public link?: string,
    public icon?: string,
    public isExpanded?: boolean,
    public children?: INavBarMenu []
    ) {}
}
```

**Sample of Data**

```
{"id":12,"icon":null,"name":"Prod. Control","nameDesc":null,"pID":10,"link":null,"pView":"true","pAdd":"true","pEdit":"true","pDelete":"true","children":[{"id":33,"icon":null,"name":"PO Listing","nameDesc":null,"pID":12,"link":"/productionorder","pView":"true","pAdd":"true","pEdit":"true","pDelete":"true"},{"id":26,"icon":null,"name":"Design Layout","nameDesc":null,"pID":12,"link":"/designlayout","pView":"true","pAdd":"true","pEdit":"true","pDelete":"true"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way around this a few days after I posted this.

Just simply have BehaviorSubject in service to store the expanded dataNodes index then the rest are obvious.

Comment: could you please write a detailed solution here?